# Save a screenshot of a certain object on a website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash

Description of my website:

On my website people enter, watch a live stream from a remote server (not my server) and when they click on a button it report it to me and what I want to add is the ability for me to take a screenshot of this stream at the very moment when they click that button and save it on the server. They question is how to implement so? Now I just have that stream in an Iframe that shows it as a .swf object

Possible solutions I thought of but don't know whether will work are:

Embedding this Iframe inside a flash object that I will create. That means that on the website the users will see a flash object I created that all it does is to show the stream from an url I give it and when the user clicks on a button inside the html it will send the flash the command to save the screenshot now and then save it on my server (don't know how to implement it, so the second question is, if you think it will work, how to do so?).

Second solution is to have an open browser on my server that when the user clicks the button, I send an ajax request to the server that will then order the browser to take a screenshot and save it locally on the server. (again, if you think this solution will work, tell me how to implement so).

Any other solutions/suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, by accident, you can wrap your video into html5 video tag, then all you need is calling a canvas `drawImage` method with this video passed as a parameter. Here is an example, how to do this - http://www.sanraul.com/2009/12/17/using-html5-canvas-to-capture-frames-from-a-video/.

The variant with Flash solution is possible, but far from my competence. The last variant is overly complicated, IMHO.